# Keras customized callback: Grid point training termination condition

Tags: python, callback, keras, deep-learning, grid-search

I'm using `GridSearchCV` from `scikit-learn` for a grid search on my neural network in `keras`. I want to customize the `callback` so each time that, the network training on one grid point finishes, I can print that the that fit is done.

Suppose that I define my grid as follows:

```
param_grid = dict(epochs=[50, 100, 500, 1000],
              learn_rate=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], 
              momentum=[0.01, 0.1], 
              dropout_rate=[0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2])
```

I calculate the total number of possibilities on the grid as:

```
grid_size = reduce(lambda x,y: x*y,[len(param_grid_[key]) for key in param_grid])
```

The callbacks are:

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
# checkpoint
filepath="best_model.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, 
save_best_only=True, mode='max')
# Early stoping
monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=1e-5, patience=200, 
verbose=1, mode='auto')

callbacks_list = [checkpoint, monitor, LiveGridReport()]
```

where `LiveGridReport()` is my customized callback that prints the message about finishing the training on a grid point.

```
class LiveGridReport(keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def __init__(self, grid_size):
        grid_size_ = grid_size

    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        return

    def on_train_end(self, logs={}):
        return
```

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to detect that training on a grid point has terminated, taking into account that I have also `EarlyStopping` callback.

Answer (score 1):

Determining in which epoch training stopped when using `EarlyStopping` callback can be done either using [stopped_epoch](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L461)

```
EarlyStopping.stopped_epoch
```

or using history

```
history = model.fit(....)
number_of_epochs_it_ran = len(history.history['loss'])
```